# how to change date format of datetime format in php

Tags: php

i have mysql database in that i have one field of datetime datatype
where date is stored as

```
2013-09-07 13:20:35
```

now i want to display this date and time on webpage something like this

```
07-09-2013 1:20:35 AM
```

is there any php function/method to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code

```
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($yourVariable));
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd certainly *hope* that date values aren't actually *stored* in a textual format at all, any more than numbers are. It's a bit like asking the database to store numbers as hex instead of decimal.

You should separate the inherent values within the data from the textual format applied to them when you present them. Normally I'd recommend formatting the data at the *client* side instead (which typically has more user context) but you can specify a format in the `SELECT` statement as well:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(StartDate, '%d-%m-%y') FROM SomeTable
```

Likewise when inserting or updating data, I would try to use parameterized SQL so that you don't specify dates as *text* at all - normally the client library should be able to pass the data on to the database in a native binary format.

In general, you should avoid string conversions unless they're actually necessary (e.g. for display to the user). They're very often a source of subtle errors, particularly around internationalization (where date formats can differ between cultures). See [my blog post on data meaning](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/06/21/but-what-does-it-all-mean.aspx) for more details.